# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hide'?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I found few solutions to deal with this AttributeError but none of them are able to solve this error.

```
def showDiscEntries(self):

        for i in range(1, 7):
            self.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit, "Discipline"+str(i)).hide()
            self.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit, "Input"+str(i)).hide()
            self.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit, "Output"+str(i)).hide()
        self.pushButton11.show()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hide'

Comment: It can't hide a `None` object. One of the lines in for loop is returning None. Figure out which one.

Comment: I tried changing the widget type and it works properly, no errors so maybe the LineEdit does not support the command which I am trying to give.

Answer (score 1):

You call `hide()` on the returned node from `self.findChild(...)`.

The problem is that `self.findChild(...)` returned `None` (it didn't find the tag you thought it would), so you actually try to call `hide()` on `None`.